# Как интегрируют PayPass и ему подобные?

Tags: android, mobile-development

В мобильной разработке я новичок, по этому хотелось бы поспрашивать у тех кто этим занимается уже давно. Подскажите можно ли интегрировать в приложение для android способ оплаты paypass или же ему подобные ? Как вообще их интегрируют ? Это часть функционала предоставляемого операционной системой либо часть API компании Мастер Кард (если так то как интегрировать его, для этого как я понимаю требуется заключение договора с мастер кардом)?

хочу сделать нечто вроде кашелька.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень амбициозная задача. Сейчас на все устройства используют 3 основных способа оплаты это AndroiPay, ApplePay или SamsungPay. Все они имеют договоры с банками, карты которых поддерживают. Если мы ходим просто добавить способ оплаты в приложение, то можно использовать это [pay api](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/paymentrequest/tutorial)

Comment: Благодарю, получается самый удобный на текущий момент способ - это интеграция AndroiPay. Не могли бы Вы еще скинуть ссылку на описание их условий сотрудничества (комиссии проценты и тому подобное... А так же что требуется для заключения договоров с ними) ?

Comment: И еще вопрос они по всему миру работают верно ?

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужна эта форма https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdwEMqa9qw4KvgqYisoUU3oJmAbVnvE4mwYsJVVjONTCf-_sQ/viewform